# Can't figure how routing for controllers works

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I'm new to ASP.Net and I'm building a website with Blazor server-side and I'm trying to post a form from the client to a controller like this :

Code for the client (located in */pages*) :

```
private async void LogIn()
{
    isSubmitting = true;
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logInForm);
    var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    //The base adress correspond to "https://localhost:port/"
    string adress = WebClient.httpClient.BaseAddress + "log_in";
    var result = await WebClient.httpClient.PostAsync(adress, data);
    isSubmitting = false;
}
```

Code for the server (located in */controllers*) :

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _db;
    public UserManager<AppUser> _manager;

    public UserController(AppDbContext db, UserManager<AppUser> manager)
    {
        _db = db;
        _manager = manager;
    }

    [Route("log_in")]
    [HttpPost]
    private async Task<IActionResult> LogIn([FromBody]LogInForm userForm)
    {
        var user = new AppUser { UserName = userForm.mail, Email = userForm.mail };
        var result = await _manager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, userForm.password);

        return null;
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, `PostAsync()` never redirect to the `LogIn()` method and return with an HTTP 400 error.

I learned first how to do it with `PostJsonAsync()` but it was using Blazor WebAssembly, which is in preview so I can't use it in production. I tried to find an answer on Internet first but there is no clear information on how to do it for Blazor server-side.

Any chance I could get a quick and simple explanation on what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Please test your URL by post man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default routing in asp.net is

```
weburl.com/{controller}/{action}
```

this would mean the url you're looking for is probably

```
weburl.com/user/log_in
```

see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: In the end, with a bit of reading and experimenting, I came across this solution. But then I understood that a Blazor Server Side project doesn't need to make Http request because everything is happening on the server. Thanks for the answer though.